# Getting a list of running workflows?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'd like to see a List of all Workflows currently running in the entire Farm. I know that you can use /_layouts/wrkmng.aspx to get some numbers, but i'll need to know the actual workflows (and the sites/lists/items they run on)

Comment: Great question. This should be an entry in Central Admin for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing the code out (sorry), you could iterate each site collection in a farm, and use the API members in Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow namespace to get the info you need.

Comment: could you share the final outcome?  I've got a script that loops thru SPSites > SPWebs > SPLists > SPListItems and looks in the Workflows collection for any with SPWorkflow.InternalStatus of "Running"....however, this is not very scalable as my production farm has thousands of SPWebs within a few hundred site collections.  I need a more efficient way to find running workflows without going all the way down to the ListItem level.